# Octave package does not aper in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, octave

I'm trying to install Octave in my work computer but I can't make it. I want use Cygwin to install a package called octave-3.8.2-1 but I can't find it. Any clue why it does not appear where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Cygwin it's in the "math" section. Are you really stuck to cygwin? If not I would suggest the inofficial installer from http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I did checked the "math" section and it isn't there. My guess is that it octave 3.8.2 it's not compatible with Windows 8 and consequently the package is not available. I'll try the no official installer plus the bat files for Windows 8. It should work.